# Brackets error: failed to connect to NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am facing brackets error after installing an extension `brackets-npm-registry`. Its prompting `Failed to connect to NodeJs.`

How to solve this error ?

Comment: [link to my screen shot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8359963/9037427/e8131a7a-3a08-11e5-868a-9c81ab8f2617.png)

Comment: Please read the help information linked at the top of every Stackoverflow page, it will guide you on how to write a good question for this site. The information will also explain all about what reputation means here.

Answer (score -1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/issues/410) on the brackets-git repo. There may be workarounds/solutions on the linked issue page.

[This comment by @anukanth](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/issues/410#issuecomment-101851134) has been reported (in a linked issue) useful to fix the issue.

> You have to manually edit C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/host with notepad and enter a line without any comment sign (#) and enter the following line without any add on like comma or anything.
>   127.0.0.1 localhost